# Why does the $\LaTeX$ cases environment not work?

Tags: support

In the last few days I have twice tried to use \cases in $\LaTeX$ and gotten nowhere.  Why does it not work?

Or, if it does, how does it work?

Comment: Would you be so kind as to show *how* it's not working? That is, is it rendering incorrectly or just not at all?

Comment: It's rendering incorrectly. I can't get multiple lines even when I use \\ to separate them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Care to share an example, below taken from [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/tex/displays.html) appears to be displaying correctly for me here on meta.

\begin{equation*}
|x|= 
\begin{cases} x & \text{if $x≥0$,}
\\
-x &\text{if $x\le 0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Code used to generate this:

```
\begin{equation*}
    |x|= 
    \begin{cases} x & \text{if $x≥0$,}
    \\
    -x &\text{if $x\le 0$.}
    \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
```

Comment: Well, I don't know *what* I was doing wrong; clearly it does work. Thanks

Comment: @PeterFlom see also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference which is full of goodies :)